# VSCode - how to keybind an external command

Tags: visual-studio-code, puppet, lint

Im trying to run "puppet-lint -f (currently open file)

The Puppet extenstion provides puppet-lint check, but doesnt auto fix any issues, it just gives warnings. How can I add a keyboard shortcut to run "puppet-lint -f" on a file Im currently editing?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know anything about the Puppet extension but in general here is how you can bind a shell command to a keychord:

Make a task for it (`.vscode/tasks.json`):

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [{
         "label": "node version",
         "command": "node",
         "args": [
             "-v"
         ],
         "type": "shell"
    }]
}
```

In the `args` you may use `${file}` for the current file.

Then add this option to your `keybindings.json` (you can find them in Command Palette under “Preferences: Open keyboard shortcuts (JSON)”):

```
{
    "key": "shift+escape",
    "command": "workbench.action.tasks.runTask",
    "args": "node version"
  },
```

Comment: configured it like this, (for some reason my code markdown isnt adding line breaks here)


tasks.json

`{

    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "puppetlint",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "puppet-lint",
            "args": ["-f", "${file}"]
        }
    ]
}`



Keybindings.json

`[
    {
        "key":"Alt+L", "command":"workbench.action.tasks.runTask",
        "args": "puppetlint"
    }
]`

working perfectly. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

co-author of the extension here. You can have the Puppet VSCode Extension run puppet-lint fix on the current file by using the `Format Document` command. You can then configure VSCode to run format on save.